Looking for reference on Vopenka's theorem on generic extensions of HOD
Chapter 15 of the third edition of Jech's textbook on set theory gives Vopenka's theorem as saying that if $V=L[A]$ where $A$ is a set of ordinals then $V$ is a set generic extension of $HOD$, whereas an article of Hugh Woodin gives Vopenka's theorem as saying (provably in $\textsf{ZF}$ alone) that for all ordinals $\alpha$, $HOD(V_{\alpha})$ is a symmetric generic extension of $HOD$, which seems at least at first sight to be a stronger statement. Is there a reference for the proof of the second version of the theorem?

The first place I'd look for this (If I had it handy) is "Intermediate submodels and generic extensions  in set theory" Ann. Math. 101 (1975) 447--490. It may also be in the book "Theory of Semisets" by Vopenka and  Hajek.

What about Theorem 6 in The HOD Dichotomy

As a (tardy) addendum to Andreas Blass's comment:  see Theorem C of Grigorieff's paper, availble via:  https://%20https://people.math.wisc.edu/~awmille1/old/m873-03/grigor.pdf
